# select max codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to get an max value with codeigniter from an table but it isnt working. This is the error i get:

> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to
>   string
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 427

This is my function:

```
public function getPeriodeNummer($bedrijf_id) {
    $this->db->select_max('id');
    $this->db->where('bedrijf_id', $bedrijf_id);
    $result = $this->db->get('rapporten');

    $this->db->select('periode_nummer');
    $this->db->where('rapporten_id', $result);
    $query = $this->db->get('statistieken_onderhoud');

    $data = $query + 1;

    return $data;
}
```

What im trying to do is as followed:

1. Select the highest `id` where `bedrijf_id` = `$bedrijf_id` from `rapporten`.
2. Select the `periode_nummer` from `statistieken_onderhoud` where `rapporten_id` = the highest `id` i got from step 1.
3. Add 1 to the `periode_nummer` i got from step 2 and `return` that number.

Thanks in forward for your help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
public function getPeriodeNummer($bedrijf_id) {
    $this->db->select_max('id');
    $this->db->where('bedrijf_id', $bedrijf_id);
    $res1 = $this->db->get('rapporten');

    if ($res1->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $res2 = $res1->result_array();
        $result = $res2[0]['id'];

        $this->db->select('periode_nummer');
        $this->db->where('rapporten_id', $result);
        $query = $this->db->get('statistieken_onderhoud');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->result_array();
            $data['query'] = 1 + $row[0]['periode_nummer'];
        }

        return $data['query'];
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: And this works perfectly, now the challenge to see what its doing to learn from it. But it works, thanks alot!.

Comment: @Angus -- Please see CodeIgniter's user guide entries for [example queries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html) and [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) for further explanation and reference for the functions I used.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $this->db->select_max('display_sequence');
    $this->db->from('acl_menu');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $r=$query->result();
```

Display Sequence is your  column name & acl_menu is your table name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an object as a string. Use this:

```
public function getPeriodeNummer($bedrijf_id) {
    $this->db->select_max('id');
    $this->db->where('bedrijf_id', $bedrijf_id);
    $result = $this->db->get('rapporten');

    $this->db->select('periode_nummer');
    $this->db->where('rapporten_id', $result);
    $query = $this->db->get('statistieken_onderhoud');
    // fetch first row in object
    $result = $query->row();
    $data = $result + 1;

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select_max('id', 'max_id');
$query = $this->db->get('video_processing');

return $query->row();
```

try the above:

Answer (score 0):

I think the `$query` variable is holding a mysql result resource and it cannot be used as a String or in this case an Integer.

You could try this way:

```
$data = mysql_result($query,0) + 1;
```

Comment: Tried it, but didnt work, I also tried to make `$result` and mysql_result but that gave me this error `Message: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given`

Answer (score 0):

Shortest:

```
$this->db->select_max('id', 'max_id')->get('video_processing')->row();
```